# How to get Vault (Secrets Engine) to work from a Docker Container inside Github Actions using Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, github-actions, hashicorp-vault

I've been having some issues getting Hashicorp Vault to launch from a Docker Container inside Github Actions using Docker Compose. Locally it works flawlessly (unsealed and has a working secrets/pki engines for my local dev setup).

Below is my `Dockerfile` for Vault:

```
FROM alpine:3.16

RUN apk --update --no-cache add vault curl tini libcap bash openssl net-tools ca-certificates

RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ENV UID=10001

RUN addgroup -S vault-service

RUN adduser -D \
    --disabled-password \ 
    --uid "${UID}" \
    vault-user \
    -G vault-service

RUN setcap cap_ipc_lock=+ep "$(readlink -f /usr/sbin/vault)"

USER vault-user

VOLUME ["/vault/ssl", "/vault/config", "/vault/audit", "/vault/data"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--", "vault"]
```

And below is the spec of the Vault Container in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
vault:
    build:
      context: ./vault
    command: server -dev -dev-root-token-id $VAULT_TOKEN -dev-listen-address "0.0.0.0:8200"
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          'CMD',
          'curl',
          '-skXGET',
          'http://localhost:8200/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true',
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 40s
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    expose:
      - 8200
```

It should work immediately as other images work inside Github Actions.

Comment: Could you post the github actions file

Comment: Here it is https://gist.github.com/phr3nzy/7eaa81d922167f3fa65acad7a7535145 @paltaa

Comment: Instead of mounting vault you could use ansible-vault to encrypt files and then decrypt with the key stored as a repo secret. Also, instead of building the container, mount the volume with the secrets. Also, you are not posting the error

Comment: I'm only in need of the PKI functionalities from Vault (Generating certificates from its root/intermediate CA).

The error I receive is vague as it only says vault isn't connecting, but the container is launching (I have a bash script that calls the Vault http API to make sure it's alive, so the only error I get is the one I wrote whenever the script timeouts and logs its message).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I also need the HTTP API provided by Vault as all my services rely on it.